# Rmarkdown default .tex overrides a custom .sty when I knit a document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I use RStudio, RMarkdown, and `knitr` frequently to build `.pdf` reports, articles, and presentations.  I developed custom `.sty` files for my reports and articles; in my `.sty` for a report, the title page includes several images whose sizes I have altered in the `.sty`.  The report `.sty` creates the title page appropriately when used in a `LaTeX` environment.

When I use the `.sty` file with `knitr` from inside RStudio, the default `.tex` file from RMarkdown overrides the `\maketitle` command from my `.sty` file and alters the images on my title page to conform to the image-scaling parameters Rmarkdown .tex file.

Is there a way that I can force the `.sty` with the correct title page construction to take precedence over how RMarkdown thinks the images should be constructed?  The `.sty` only sets the title page and the headers and footers.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. You could take the original default Latex tamplate and alter it for your needs: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/tree/master/inst/rmd/latex